# Twitter: direct message with quick reply is missing buttons

Tags: rest, button, twitter, message

I am building a Twitter chatbot and I need quick reply buttons on direct messages.

After my [failed hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489322/twitter-error-sending-direct-message-with-quick-reply-buttons) on the excellent Tweetinvi library (does not support the quick reply yet) I tried to go back to the roots and used [Twurl](https://github.com/twitter/twurl) to simplify the problem.

I tried with the [sample provided by Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/quick-replies/api-reference/options) with minor editing:

- changed user id;
- replaced CR LF with nothing
- removed the ' in what's

Finally the message is sent **but** I can see only the text without the quick reply buttons.

Here is my twurl command line

```
twurl authorize (the 4 tokens)
twurl account
```

(the account is authorized)

```
twurl -t -A 'Content-type: application/json' /1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json -d '{"event":{"type":"message_create","message_create":{"target":{"recipient_id":"999999999"},"message_data":{"text":"What syourfavoritetypeofbird?","quick_reply":{"type":"options","options":[{"label":"RedBird","description":"Adescriptionabouttheredbird.","metadata":"external_id_1"},{"label":"BlueBird","description":"Adescriptionaboutthebluebird.","metadata":"external_id_2"},{"label":"BlackBird","description":"Adescriptionabouttheblackbird.","metadata":"external_id_3"},{"label":"WhiteBird","description":"Adescriptionaboutthewhitebird.","metadata":"external_id_4"}]}}}}}'
```

That's Twitter response:

```
-> "status: 200 OK\r\n"
-> "strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519\r\n"
-> "x-access-level: read-write-directmessages\r\n"
-> "x-connection-hash: b85f0c59aeb2f9b8b4c439fb448e541a\r\n"
-> "x-content-type-options: nosniff\r\n"
-> "x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN\r\n"
-> "x-response-time: 225\r\n"
-> "x-transaction: 006a0b630064b6c7\r\n"
-> "x-tsa-request-body-time: 0\r\n"
-> "x-twitter-response-tags: BouncerCompliant\r\n"
-> "x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
```

The message format seems ok (I got errors when I used the ' in text) but I do not see the buttons, so I ask for advice.

Note: to install twurl on Windows I followed [this excellent tutorial](http://sgomez.blogspot.it/2015/10/running-twurl-on-windows.html)

Comment: Hi, I will look into it as soon as possible but I am running out of time at the current moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was malformed Json.

with this

```
{"event": {"type": "message_create","message_create": {"target": {"recipient_id": "12345"},"sender_id": "6789","message_data": {"text": "Choose your destiny","quick_reply": {"type": "options","options": [{"label": "one","metadata": "1","description": "One descr"},{"label": "Two","metadata": "2","description": "Descr 2}]}}}}}
```

it works.

Comment: Are you sure it works? You're missing a quote at the end of the last description: it ends like this: `"Descr 2}]}}}}}` instead of `"Descr 2"}]}}}}}`.

Comment: I've tried to send quick replies via twurl (using your JSON, plus the missing quote), and the message goes through, Twitter echoes back the "quick_reply" object, which would appear to confirm that it is correctly parsing it, but no buttons appear. Is it just that I am missing something? Like … a "business" account, or a developer account? Thanks in advance.